# Implementation of List.of_seq

Tags: ocaml

If we look at the source for the OCaml [`List` module](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/list.ml), `of_seq` is defined as:

> ```
> let[@tail_mod_cons] rec of_seq seq =
>   match seq () with
>   | Seq.Nil -> []
>   | Seq.Cons (x1, seq) ->
>       begin match seq () with
>       | Seq.Nil -> [x1]
>       | Seq.Cons (x2, seq) -> x1 :: x2 :: of_seq seq
>       end
> ```

This makes perfect sense *except* why is the extra work performed within the function as opposed to writing the seemingly more straightforward following function?

```
let[@tail_mod_cons] rec of_seq seq =
  match seq () with
  | Seq.Nil -> []
  | Seq.Cons (x1, seq) -> x1 :: of_seq seq
```

What insight am I missing to make this make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like straightforward loop unrolling to me. I.e., it spreads the loop overhead over twice as many calls to `seq ()`

Comment: It also reduces the recursion depth, i.e. less stack space is needed.

Comment: Actually I think the purpose of `[@tail_mod_cons]` is to make the function use a constant amount of stack space.

Comment: This is indeed the purpose of `[@tail_mod_cons]`.

Comment: I see from other discussions that this appears to be done to avoid tail_mod_cons from having a detrimental effect on performance. The same is at work in the implementation of `List.map`.

Comment: @Chris would you mind sourcing these discussions? I'm interested in what exactly makes `[@tail_mod_cons]` behave poorly in this example.

Comment: https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/stdlib-list-loop-unrolling/11262